# android google tv actionbar onfocus event

Tags: android, android-actionbar, google-tv

I am new to android development, and I am trying to develop an simple android application for google tv and would like to create a tabbed layout similar to the leftNavBar library provided in the googletv-android-sample or just using the original actionbar tabs layout. However, I am looking for a solution to attach the onFocus event to the tab so that i can switch the content fragment when a tab gains focus, instead of selected event. Thank you.

An approach is given here by implementing onfouschangelistener on leftnavbar library.

[Change ImageView when Tab Focus changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168000/change-imageview-when-tab-focus-changes)

Any other thoughts would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are asking - please revise your question. Why do you want to use onHover? why is using OnFocusChangeListener an issue?

Example onFocusChange:

```
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
  if(hasFocus){ 
      view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
  } else {
      view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
  }
}
```

Comment: OnFocus event would actually serve the my purpose, but I had trouble working it out with the action bar with navigation tab view. The only event I could get was selected event inherited from TabListener.

Comment: what about using the OnItemSelectedListener - the navigation tab is a list - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html